# Reaching the root directory of linux kernel source on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am running ubuntu 13.10 on linux kernel version 3.11.0-12.I have to add a system call in this but i am facing a problem. The very first step says that I have to change my current working directory to kernel directory. 
I used the command " cd linux-3.11.0-12 " but it is showing that no such file or directory exists. Please tell me where am i going wrong and how do I correct this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, you want to add a system call to the Linux kernel, but you don't know how to reach the source code? Are you sure you are able to modify, configure, build, install and boot the Linux kernel?

Assuming yes, you need to get the source code of Linux first (for example, by cloning https://github.com/torvalds/linux or just downloading the version you are interested in), extract it somewhere and then `cd` to the path where you extracted it. Then you can begin modifying to your heart's content.

Perhaps [this blog post](http://blog.techveda.org/adding-system-calls-linux-kernel-3-5-x/) could help you.

Comment: On a Ubuntu system, on might want to start with the appropriate kernel source deb package corresponding to the ubuntu release and running kernel version, not a vanilla upstream kernel.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I have done this before many times and it's not so problematic. You can always checkout the vanilla version corresponding to the kernel you are running (which is not necessary either) and copy the configuration file from `/boot` and use that as a base. In fact, those configuration files have a huge number of drivers enabled to be as generic as possible which one might want to disable first.

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  But particularly for a newbie, there's a lot to be said for changing as little as possible.  In fact, I always suggest that people rebuild and try the existing kernel with **no changes whatsoever** to validate the process, before making any code changes.  That way when the modified version fails it is clear that this is due to a problem introduced with the modification, and not using the wrong source or build or install process.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, sure. Having never tried the source package I can't really know. But as far as I can tell, getting a vanilla kernel with the same version as the kernel installed and copying over the configuration file from `/boot` should be equally easy and trouble-less!

Answer (score 0):

To get the source of the installed kernel on ubuntu, you can use the command [for ubuntu 13.04+ ]

```
apt-get source linux-image-`uname -r`
```

and should be typically be placed under /usr/src

Reference:

[1] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile
[2] https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel